# How do I 'UnHotkey' a spell/item in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

I know how to hotkey on Skyrim on ps3, but I cant figure out how to unhotkey unless I have to load from a previous save.

Is this possible? I havent been able to find any info on how.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean Favoriting/Unfavoriting? Ps3 doesn't use hotkeys like a PC.

When in your inventory/spell or ability list, there should be an indicator in one of the screen corners (lower right?) telling you which button is *Favorite*. Once you've favorited that item, the same button should change to indicate *Unfavorite.*

So it's as simple as pressing the same button you used to add it to the favorites list in the first place. :)